# Value not being inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with some code that involves MySQL. I create the table and everything is fine until there in an error in the xml that I receive. I added this code:

```
if(isset($items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount) !== False) { 
     $amount = $items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
}else{
     $amount = 'None';
}
$sqlImport = "INSERT INTO " . $fileName . "(id, asin, amount, salesRank)
VALUES($id, '$asin', $amount, $salesRank)";
```

When I run this code it give me this error

```
Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'
```

I am not sure what the problem is and if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you do with $amount var after that?

Comment: edited the code. Thanks!

Comment: try to escape $amount with '' in your SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

you forget to put `$amount` and `$salesRank` in 2 single quotas and you should to know varchar value should be in 2 `'` so your query should be:

```
$sqlImport = "INSERT INTO " . $fileName . "(id, asin, amount, salesRank)
VALUES('$id', '$asin', '$amount', '$salesRank')";
```

Comment: How about $id? it is a string of numbers.

Comment: if a string you should also but in 2 single quotas

Answer (score 0):

change your sql to the below

> $sqlImport = "INSERT INTO $fileName (id, asin, amount, salesRank)
>   VALUES ($id, $asin, $amount, $salesRank)";